# How to apply benchmark methods to multiple time series in R

Tags: r, loops, time-series

My data structure is as follows
[data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCHk7.png)

I have many locations which I need to forecast the number of customer complaints in the next week or next two weeks. How can I write a loop for different locations to find the best benchmark models (naive,mean,drift,snaive), adding ets and auto.arima would be better.